# Switching between macros located in different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Let's assume I have 2 different files: "1" and "a1".
I want to open second one using macro from "1" and then run a code from "a1"

So, in "1" I have following code:

```
Sub anotherMacro()
Dim path As String
Dim Fname As String
Dim macroName As String

path = ActiveWorkbook.path
Fname = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Workbooks.Open (path & "\a" & Fname)
Application.Run "a1.xlsm!Module1.SecondMacro"
MsgBox "Am I still here?"

End Sub
```

Second macro in file "a1" looks like that:

```
Sub SecondMacro()
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

When I'm using Application.Run command, the msgbox is not being executed. The "a1" is getting opened, closed and then there is no further action.

Is there a way to get back to "1" and display the msgbox?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that after executing `Workbook.Close`, the VBA stops executing. Therefore, you should be careful of codes placed after the Workbook.Close.

You may consider transfer the `Workbook.Close` method to 1.xlsm. Perform any actions before you execute the `Workbook.Close` method.

I modified the codes as follows.

**1.xlsm**
Module1

```
Option Explicit

Sub anotherMacro()
    Dim path As String
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim macroName As String

    With Application
        path = .ThisWorkbook.path
        Fname = .ThisWorkbook.Name

        .Workbooks.Open (path & "\a" & Fname)
        .Run "a1.xlsm!Module1.SecondMacro"
    End With
End Sub

Sub WelcomeBack()
    MsgBox "Am I still here?"

    Application.ThisWorkbook.Activate
        ' Activate 1.xlsm. This is optional, depending on your needs.

    ' Add code here to perform any further actions.

    Application.Workbooks("a1.xlsm").Close
        ' Close a1.xlsm. VBA stops here.
End Sub
```

**a1.xlsm**
Module1

```
Option Explicit

Sub SecondMacro()
    ' Add code here to perform any actions.

    Application.Run "1.xlsm!Module1.WelcomeBack"
        ' Go back to 1.xlsm
End Sub
```

PS: Check out the difference between [`Application.ActiveWorkbook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-activeworkbook-property-excel) and [`Application.ThisWorkbook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-thisworkbook-property-excel).

Answer (score 0):

If you put your VBA code in an XLAM file instead of an XLSM file, then you can add it as an Excel Add-In and it can then communicate with all workbooks simultaneously.